# Are SVG user units the values used in the SVG XML?

Tags: svg, inkscape

It's a bit hard to grasp the *user unit* (aka *SVG user units*) concept at first, though many resources try to explain this. For my purpose, I simply need to know the following. Consider this bit of SVG XML:

```
<rect width="600" height="200" x="0" y="0" />
```

Are those numbers not given in *user units*? Or in other words, am I correct to say that this rectangle is 600 user units wide?

Comment: I really don't think the question suggested to already have an answer, does answers my question. The questions are related, and if one already has a firm understanding of exactly what is meant by user unit and/or pixel, in the given context, then it probably does answer the question.

Comment: But for someone just trying to understand SVG documentation/terminology, and exporting other formats from Inkscape, it does not answer the very simple question I tried to ask. The suggested post even introduces the concept of CSS, and it should not be necessary for someone to also study CSS (another layer of complexity), in order to get an answer to this simple question.

Comment: Yes in your example width=600 are 600 user units. Probably the main reason we need the concept of svg user-units instead of just using pixels: depending on the viewBox and width and heights specified in the parent svg (or applied as CSS properties) user units may not correspond to screen pixels. Besides some elements like `<rect>`, `<circle>`, `<line>` also accept relative units like "%" or "real-life" absolute units in(inch) or cm that are internally converted to user units. Please see the[ w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units)